# Is $f$ a injective function?

Tags: analysis

For conclude a exercise i need to know is $f$ is a injective function or not, but i dont know how to do it. I just try the usual way, $x,y$ in the domain, if $f(x) = f(y) \rightarrow x=y$ then it is, but i get nothing.

The function $f$ is $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$, $f(x,y) = (x^2 - y^2, 2xy)$.

Comment: Compare $f(x,y)$ and $f(-x,-y)$.

Comment: $f$ is a function of two variables. Assume $(x,y), (u,v)$ are in its domain, and $f(x,y) = f(u,v)$. Write out what that means. Now do you "get something"?

Comment: I notice that $f$ is isomorphic to $g(z) = z^2,  z\in \mathbb C$